# How can I customize the list of test run available outcomes?

Tags: azure-devops

Currently when running a test case I have a set of test outcomes to choose from. If a manual test case was marked as Failed and its bug was resolved I would like to change its status to "Re-Run". However the is no such outcome.

I would like to customize the process and add that option.

Tried to edit the process from the process editor, however the Pass \ Failed \ ect... options are not even displayed there for test runs.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I customize the list of test run available outcomes?

For this issue ,There is currently no out-of-the-box method to customize the list of test run available outcomes in azure devops. Test outcomes are designed like this ,as far as I know, there is currently no way to customize it in azure devops.

But you can try to write an extension to achieve customizing the list of test run available outcomes feature.

You could also submit a feature request in our [Develop Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/21/index.html) site. Our PM and product team will kindly review your suggestion.